# Disable a Picker option in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to disable an option of Picker in swiftUI.
According documentation below code is suppose to work:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let options = ["All", "Men", "Women", ]
    @State private var selectedOption = "All"

    var body: some View {
        Picker("Options", selection: $selectedOption) {
            ForEach(options, id: \.self) { option in
                Text(option)
                    .disabled(option == "All")
            }
        }
    }

}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, It's not working where I have went wrong. Can anyone help!?

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working"? What actually happened when you use this code? Is there an error message? What does the error say?

Comment: Your example is a little strange, you have "All" as default and still you want to disable it? Is this some kind of dynamic functionality, maybe it's better to filter the data source instead?

Comment: And what documentation are you referring to?

Comment: This is an example code @Sweeper. I need to grey out the disabled option dynamically. There is no error message.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/list/disabled(_:) 
This the documentation @JoakimDanielson

Comment: Filter the data source (`options`) dynamically instead.

Comment: Ok but that documentation is not specific to Picker

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't disable an option in SwiftUI Picker. The *disabled* modifier can be applied on the whole picker. So one way is, you can filter the options when adding to the picker.

```
let options = ["All", "Men", "Women"]
    @State private var selectedOption = "Men"

    var body: some View {
        Picker("Options", selection: $selectedOption) {
            ForEach(options, id: \.self) { option in
                if option != "All" {
                    Text(option)

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Another option is, you can use ***SwiftUI Menu*** to make a custom Picker and get your expected result. Here you can disable any option you want,

```
       let options = ["All", "Men", "Women"]
        @State private var selectedOption = "Men"

        var body: some View {
            Menu {
                ForEach(options, id: \.self) { option in
                    if option == "All" {
                        Button(action: {}) {
                            Text(option)
                                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        }
                        .disabled(true)
                    } else {
                        Button(action: {
                            selectedOption = option
                        }) {
                            Text(option)
                        }
                    }
                }
            } label: {
                Text(selectedOption)
                    .foregroundColor(.primary)
                    .padding(.horizontal)
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
        }
```